# How to convert KotlinByteArray to string and vice versa?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I am calling a function from kotlin to swift, where I have to convert KotlinByteArray to string and string to KotlinByteArray.

The function call is in swift side. So have to convert on swift code.

Comment: [decode-to-string](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/decode-to-string.html), [encode-to-byte-array](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/encode-to-byte-array.html)

Comment: I am writing this code in swift. So I have to convert this in Xcode.

Comment: @RajeshMaurya did you find a solution? If yes pleas post it.

Comment: @stackich check Artyom's answer. In your swift code just find the utility function - it will be part of a file/class where declared.

Answer (score 1):

The best option here would be to provide wrappers for stdlib functions `String.encodeToByteArray()` and `ByteArray.decodeToString()`, which were suggested by @IR42. Just put into your Kotlin/Native code something like

```
fun String.ExportedToByteArray(startIndex: Int, 
    endIndex: Int, 
    throwOnInvalidSequence: Boolean
): ByteArray {
return this.encodeToByteArray(startIndex, endIndex, throwOnInvalidSequence)
}
```

Then, you'll be able to use them directly from your Swift code. 
 A word about reasons for such a complicated approach. Those functions do not get into your frameworks' API by default because the compiler cannot choose which part of the stdlib should be exported. So, it was designed to make a developer specify needed functions explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing in a below-mentioned way-

```
val valueInString="123456"

val valueInByteArray = ByteArray(valueInString)
```

Comment: I have to do in swift. I know this is very easy in kotlin.